# Slideshow and Transition on Iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, slideshow, transition

I have wired Problems with the following code.

If I use these code and i run it on the simulator he only shows me the first two pictures in the array with the transition. If i run it on the Iphone he shows me just the first picture.
Also he does not repeat the pictures.-

What iam doing wrong?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    welcomePhoto = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bild.jpeg",@"Bild1.jpeg", @"Bild2.png", nil];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[welcomePhoto objectAtIndex:0]];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)transitionPhotos{
    int photoCount;
    if (photoCount < [welcomePhoto count] - 1){
        photoCount ++;
    }else{
        photoCount = 0;
    }
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                      duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{ imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[welcomePhoto objectAtIndex:photoCount]]; }
                    completion:NULL];    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this in viewDidLoad.

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:animatedImageView];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bild.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bild.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bild.png"], nil]; //etc
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 3.0f * [animatedImageView.animationImages count];
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Comment: thx your code is working. How can add transition to your code? is there a other way like i did?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
    NSArray *imagesArray;
 int photoCount;
 UIImageView *imageView;
-(void)setupImageView{
     photoCount = 0;
     [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgA.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgB.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgC.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgD.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgE.png"] , nil];         imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
     imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount];
     [self.view addSubview:imageView];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }

 -(void)transitionPhotos{


if (photoCount < [imagesArray count] - 1){
    photoCount ++;
}else{
    photoCount = 0;
}
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView1
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount]; }
                completion:NULL];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. You should skip initializing photoCount in transitionPhotos. Make it an iVar or property.